# a solver for large instances of ACVRP

Tags: vehicle-routing

I want to solve large instances of asymmetrical capacitated vehicle problem with thousands of nodes. So far I tried lkh-3 solver but so far I cannot reach noticably better results compared to naive solution used as initial solution for the solver

Even good/optimal solution for a problem calculated in days is good for me for comparison with worse and faster solutions.

Comment: Google OR Tools?

Comment: Vrp solver in ortools focus on smaller instances with additional constraints without ambition to compete with lkh or concorde on larger instances. Cp-sat solver also fails with its circuit constraint implementing hamiltonian cycle when number of nodes is a few hundreds.

Comment: Maybe Thibaut Vidal's [HGS-CVRP](https://github.com/vidalt/HGS-CVRP/)? It scales very well up to a thousand nodes, and with some parameter tweaking, I'm sure it could be made to work for instances a bit larger than that (but might not scale to 10K+).

Comment: @gregy4 thank you very much for the comment, I really didn't know that.